# How can i start a program that you browsed and place

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox

I want to make a browse button and when you searched your program and `clicked ok` that it 
goes into a `TextBox`*(I got this already)* but then I want to start the program you selected with another button.

How can i do that?

This is the code i have already:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

End Sub
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Using a As New OpenFileDialog()
        If a.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.TextBox1.Text = a.FileName
        End If
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Using b As New OpenFileDialog()
        If b.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.TextBox2.Text = b.FileName
        End If
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Using c As New OpenFileDialog()
        If c.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.TextBox3.Text = c.FileName
        End If
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Using d As New OpenFileDialog()
        If d.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.TextBox4.Text = d.FileName
        End If
    End Using
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Add this to your button click event (Updated to VB.net)

```
if Not String.IsNullorEmpty(TextBox1.Text)    
   Process.Start(me.TextBox1.Text)
end if
```

Comment: if i add that and click on the button it works but if i click on the button and the textbox is empty then it crashes how to fix that?

Comment: @user1973187 check updated answer, you should check if textbox has value

Comment: that ! is fault i can't do that then i get an error it's btw Visual basics 2010 express

Comment: @user1973187 The provided code in this answer is C# not VB.NET. Replace the `!` with `Not`, remove the `{` and replace the `}` with `End If`. (Also remove the `;` on the 3rd line.)

Comment: if i start a bat through my program then by bat woudn't work well

Comment: no but i use it for a world of warcraft private server controller so i can start it up, but the mysql bat says that there is already a mysql.bat idk why